# query not functioning as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Below is my query which i'm trying to use,

```
select DISTINCT c.sno from Cards as c, reservation as r 
where c.name='CRS-4-FC' AND c.sno != r.ssno;
```

This query is supposed to select only those sno from Cards which dont exist in the reservation table ie no sno is present in the column of ssno in reservation table. I put in

```
c.sno!=r.ssno
```

so that i dont choose all the sno. But when this query runs i get all the sno rather than those that are not reserved. Can someone help out where im going wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
select DISTINCT c.sno
from Cards as c 
left outer join reservation as r on c.sno = r.ssno
where r.ssno is null
and c.name='CRS-4-FC'
```

Answer (score 1):

try `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.sno
FROM Cards c
    LEFT JOIN reservation as r
        ON c.sno = r.ssno
WHERE c.name='CRS-4-FC' AND
      r.ssno IS NULL;
```

See [Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
select DISTINCT c.sno 
from Cards as c LEFT JOIN reservation as r  
ON c.sno = r.ssno
where c.name='CRS-4-FC' AND r.ssno IS NULL;
```